# How to have a search box with search filter under dropdown menu in angular2 or later

Tags: angular, filter, drop-down-menu, angular8, search-box

I am working on  a project where I am stuck at point, I have created a dynamic dropdown menu which is getting 25-30 options from some api and I want a search box with filter in exact same format as shown below.I have search filter logic which is working fine but I am unable to put search box in below format.Here is link

https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/Angular-Sidenav

Now I need three things

1. When Page loads there should be some option selected by defualt
2. When I open my drop down menu It should have a search box and below
   search box it should have all links or options.
3. When I select any option It should get selected and vsisible in
   header as shown below .
   **Below is the plunkr link in same way i want my select tag**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq9LnK?p=preview

**Expected**
[image: Expected]

I am attaching code
**app.component.html**

```
<select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <option *ngFor="let order of orders; " [ngValue]="order">
                  {{order.name}}
  </option>
</select>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
orders=[
    { id: '1', name: 'order 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'order 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'order 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'order 4' }
  ]

  selectedDay: string = '';

  selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
  }
```

As shown above I am trying to place search box in select menu but I am unable to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ngx-mat-select-search` with angular material `mat-select` together.

here is the `ngx-mat-select-search` NPM link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search

there are some examples in the following link:

https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: what is your problem exactly? using this and a select menu is what you asked. isn't it?

Comment: I am working on liv project which need exact same select tag format shown in http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq9LnK?p=preview this link

Answer (score 0):

@ng-select works well for these types of cases and also has multiple select is you need it.

NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Demo Page: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources